# Symfony 2.3 - after moving vendors dir autoloading MyBundle got broken

Tags: php, symfony

I wanted to make vendor directory common for more than one project. So I moved it and updated my `app/autoload.php` accordingly: `($loader = require __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php')`

It worked to some degree - it seems Symfony was able to find it's way to vendors directory BUT somewhere along the way autoloading my bundles got broken. I get this:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'My\FooBundle\MyFooBundle' not found
>   in (...)\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 19

How should I solve this? Should I somehow add dir with my bundles to `app/autoload.php`?
I understand that Composer is responsible for autoloading anything within vendors dir, but not my bundles, so I guess that messing with `composer.json` doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Don't do that. Composers autoload.php loads other files with classmaps and stuff. Composer is project based, can't be used globally.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `vendor/composer/autoload_namespace.php` file. The `$vendorDir` should stay the same, but the `$baseDir` certainly needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the line "psr-0" in composer.json point to correct path. In your case, I guess it should be `YourBundleFolder/src`. Normally it's just `src` because src is same level with composer.json. Now you have moved the vendor folder, I guess you moved the composer.json also.  That's why it can not find your bundle.